# GitFlow for feature split in sub branches

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-flow, git-merge-conflict

Another GitFlow question for you :)

Can you help me understand the right procedure to apply in the case below?

I want to start the development of a new big FeatureA starting from the develop branch.
Because FeatureA is big and complex, so I want to have multiple MR to facilitate the reviewer's life.

What I usually do is:

- Cutting a branch from develop called FeatureA_Base
- Immediately cutting a branch from FeatureA_Base called FeatureA_1 to start working
- When I reach a certain amount of change then I cut the FeatureA_2 branch from FeatureA_1 and I keep doing this until the development is complete a the branch FeatureA_n
- To keep my branches up to date with develop I often merge develop into FeatureA_Base and FeatureA_Base into FeatureA_1 (this is repeated until I merge FeatureA_n-1 into FeatureA-n)

The problem comes at the point of merging everything together because I get a lot of conflicts that I don't understand.
I want to highlight that I only use merge and not rebase but when I start to merge all together I can't avoid having tons of conflicts.

What I tried to do is start to merge FeatureA_n into FeatureA_n-1, repeating the process until I merge FeatureA_1 into FeatureA_Base.
As well I tried the other way around, merging FeatureA_1 into FeatureA_Base, then FeatureA_2 into FeatureA_Base, and so on until merging FeatureA_n into FeatureA_Base.

In both cases, I was getting a lot of conflicts...

Any suggestion on how to improve this process?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Regarding your ultimate goal here: "Because FeatureA is big and complex, so I want to have multiple MR to facilitate the reviewer's life." Do you mean you want to have multiple MRs into `develop` instead of one large MR into `develop` with the entire feature?

Comment: I suspect that the `[git-flow]` tag isn't relevant here, since this appears to be only about merging a large feature into a shared branch, and it probably doesn't matter that it's `develop` or `main`, or what happens after that.

Comment: Regarding, "When I reach a certain amount of change then I cut the FeatureA_2 branch from FeatureA_1 and I keep doing this..." when you cut feature branch 2, do you also continue working separately on feature branch 1, or is it just a linear progression but on separate branches?

Comment: I want to merge only one MR into develop when the whole feature is complete, the FeatureA_Base.
It can happen that during the review process I modify FeatureA_1 while working on FeatereA_3 @TTT

Comment: OK. It's possible that it would help for each `FeatureA_X` branch to start from `FeatureA_Base` instead of the "x-1" branch. To do that each of the sub-features would need to be independent from each other, or, they would need to be created after the "x-1 branch is merged into the base feature branch. It's not clear exactly where the conflicts are coming from. If it's coming from merging in `develop`, then it makes sense that every feature branch that was created before that merge would also have conflicts.

Comment: If the conflicts are in fact coming from merging `develop` into `FeaturesA_Base`, and then propagating down, one possible fix for that, would be to wait to merge in `develop` until the base feature is done. Then you could fix the conflicts all in one shot at the end. (Though sometimes this is daunting...) This is one of the reasons long lived feature branches, especially *shared* long lived feature branches (even if just sharing with yourself), is discouraged.